# What is an entitlements plist and why do I need one?

Tags: app-store, codesign, entitlements

I have been following the instructions for app store distribution in the iOS Developer Program Guide, and I did everything it said to do, but when I try to build the app, it says "the entitlements file "path of file/entitlements.plist" is missing." I tried adding a template one and it says

`Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1`, and

`Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)`

I don't think this has to do with the certificate because I have followed Apple's intsructions about the certificate, but it doesn't say anything about an entitlements.plist.  How do I get my app to work so that I can submit it to the App Store?